# Django REST framework. How i can make export model in csv

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, export-to-csv

I have the following models:

```
class Student(models.Model):
   first_name = models.CharField(verbose_name='student first name', max_length=64)
   last_name = models.CharField(verbose_name='student last name', max_length=64)
   email = models.EmailField()

class Meta:
    db_table = 'student'

def __str__(self):
    return self.first_name + ' ' + self.last_name

class Course(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   description = models.TextField()
   start_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
   end_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)

class Meta:
    db_table = 'course'

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class CourseParticipant(models.Model):
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, related_name='courses', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student, related_name='student_name', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    completed = models.BooleanField(null=False, default=False)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'course_participant'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.course, self.student
```

And urs:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('course', CourseAPIView.as_view()),
    path('course/<int:pk>/', CourseAPIDetailView.as_view()),
    path('student', StudentAPIView.as_view()),
    path('student/<int:pk>/', StudentAPIDetailView.as_view()),
    path('student/assigned_to_course', StudentAssignedToTheCourseAPIView.as_view()),
    path('student/assign_student_to_course', StudentAssignToCourse.as_view()),
    path('student/assigned_to_course/<int:pk>/', StudentAssignedToTheCourseDetailView.as_view()),
    path('student/report/<int:pk>/', StudentReportView.as_view()),
```

]

I need made export some data in csv, in next format:

- student full name
- number of assigned courses to the student
- number of completed courses by student

For example:

```
Test Student,10, 3
Test Student1,12, 1
Test Student2,5, 3
Test Student3,5, 4
```

So, what view should be for it. I mean, how i can get data like student full name and etc. I will be grateful for the help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use Python's [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module.

---

At first, I would suggest defining `full_name` as a property in your `Student` model since it will make it clearer:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    ...

    @property
    def full_name(self):
        return self.first_name + ' ' + self.last_name
```

Then you can define a simple `APIView` for the job:

```
import csv

from django.http import HttpResponse

from rest_framework.views import APIView


class ExportCSVStudents(APIView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="export.csv"'

        writer = csv.writer(response)

        for student in Student.objects.all():
            assigned_courses = CourseParticipant.objects.filter(student=student)
            completed_courses = assigned_courses.filter(completed=True)

            row = ','.join([
                student.full_name,
                assigned_courses.count(),
                completed_courses.count()
            ])

            writer.writerow(row)

       return response
```

This should automatically download a file called `export.csv` with your desired data, after you register it in your urlconf and access it via simple HTTP GET.

Comment: Thank you. It's work is pretty well. One more question, when i tried do this for single record, i have empty csv document. I just change for student in Student.objects.filter(pk=self.kwargs['pk']): Can you explain me pls, why it so?

Comment: @MrOldSir Does this filter actually return an object?

Comment: I alredy fix it. Problem in url :). Thanks for help

Comment: hi! Im trying this code but Im not getting the export.csv file downloading on my system after making the api request any idea why